# Probability that the test produces a positive result but that the true result is negative?

Tags: probability

You take a COVID test. The test can produce a positive or negative result. What is the probability that the test produces a positive result but you don't actually have COVID?

I'm confused on whether I am supposed to compute the conditional probability here, i.e., probability that test result is positive given that you don't have COVID, or if I'm looking for the joint probability of test result producing a positive result AND you don't actually have COVID.

I think it's usually the former in these types of Bayes rule problem, but the "but..." wording is kind of confusing to me. What do you guys think? Is there a standard interpretation for "but" as it relates to conditional or joint probability?

Comment: I think the question is ambiguously worded. A third possibility is that you are supposed to compute the probability that you don’t actually have COVID given that the test is positive. That’s what I’d guess is being asked, but again, I don’t think it’s clear.

Comment: @Joe I agree. I didn't think about that 3rd possibility, which makes more sense to me the more I read that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to visualize the possibilities in a chart

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$Test +$\quad\quad$ Test -
Have COVID
Don't have COVID$\quad\;\color{red}{\Large\bullet}\;$ (False positive)

*False positive* is by **definition** the fraction of disease-free people who tested positive.

### *Added*

In the form you want,
if $D$ = diseased, $D^C$= healthy, + = test positive, - = test negative,

what you want to compute is $Pr(+|D^C)$

Comment: The wording isn't crystal clear, no. But it seems your interpretation is that it's a joint probability and not a conditional probability?

Comment: No, I perceive it as a false positive. I have added that in the answer. It is like the test returned a positive *although* you don't have COVID.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm still kind of iffy on what we're conditioning on here. Is it the probability of getting a positive conditioned on that you don't have COVID?

Comment: Yes, the fraction of disease free people tested positive, see here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-false-negatives-positives.html

Comment: @student10101: I have added the formula in the form you want.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional probability (corresponding to false positives) to be computed is $P(+|\bar{C})$, where $+$ and $C$ denote the events for testing positive and having covid, respectively. It can be computed with Bayes rule using $P(+|\bar{C})=P(\bar{C}|+)P(+)/P(\bar{C})$